# How to append something at the end of a certain line of the text

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I want to append something at the end of a certain line(have some given character).
For example, the text is:

```
Line1:  I just want to make clear of the problem
Line2:  Thanks to all who look into my problem
Line3:  How to solve the problem?
Line4:  Thanks to all.
```

Then I want to add "Please help me" at the end of

```
Line2:  Thanks to all who look into my problem
```

And `"Line2"` is the key word. (that is I have to append something by grep this line by key word).

So the text after the script should be:

```
Line1:  I just want to make clear of the problem
Line2:  Thanks to all who look into my problem Please help me
Line3:  How to solve the problem?
Line4:  Thanks to all.
```

I know `sed` can append something to certain line but, if I use `sed '/Line2/a\Please help me'`, it will insert a new line after the line. That is not what I want. I want it to append to the current line.

Could anybody help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd probably go for John's `sed` solution but, since you asked about `awk` as well:

```
$ echo 'Line1:  I just want to make clear of the problem
Line2:  Thanks to all who look into my problem
Line3:  How to solve the problem?
Line4:  Thanks to all.' | awk '/^Line2:/{$0=$0" Please help me"}{print}'
```

This outputs:

```
Line1:  I just want to make clear of the problem
Line2:  Thanks to all who look into my problem Please help me
Line3:  How to solve the problem?
Line4:  Thanks to all.
```

An explanation as to how it works may be helpful. Think of the `awk` script as follows with conditions on the left and commands on the right:

```
/^Line2:/ {$0=$0" Please help me"}
          {print}
```

These two `awk` clauses are executed for every single line processed.

If the line matches the regular expression `^Line2:` (meaning "Line2:" at the start of the line), you change `$0` by appending your desired string (`$0` is the entire line as read into `awk`).

If the line matches the empty condition (all lines will match this), `print` is executed. This outputs the current line `$0`.

So you can see it's just a simple program which modifies the line where necessary and outputs the line, modified or not.

---

In addition, you may want to use `/^Line2:/` as the key even for a `sed` solution so you don't pick up `Line2` in the middle of the text or `Line20` through `Line29`, `Line200` through `Line299` and so on:

```
sed '/^Line2:/s/$/ Please help me/'
```

Comment: paxdiablo, thanks a lot for your kindly help. Your method of awk also works.
I have to review awk to understand your method.
Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks for paxdiablo again for your so detailed explanation. Yes,/^Line2/ is better. Good suggestion!

Comment: @zhaojing, I've added some more detail as to how it works but I'd probably still go for the (modified) `sed` solution. There's little point trying to kill a fly with a thermonuclear warhead :-)

Comment: Yes, paxdiablo, I agree with you. But your awk method helps me to learn much more. Thanks again for your detailed awk explanation! :-)

Comment: I think the way of awk of paxdiablo and detailed explanation give me better insight into the problem.
I understand the solving method now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

```
sed '/Line2/ s/$/ Please help me/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Shell scripting

```
while read -r line
do 
  case "$line" in
    *Line2* ) line="$line Please help me";;
  esac
  echo "$line"
done <"file" > temp
mv temp file
```

Comment: ghostdog, many thanks for your shell script. :-). It is of great help.
But my reputation is not enough, so I am sorry I have no right to vote for your answer.
I think I have learned a lot through all of the answers.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Thanks to all of the answers. To understand all the answers makes me learn much more besides the problem itself.
Since paxdiablo's answer is very detailed to make me more clear about the question, so I vote his answer as accepted.
In fact, all the answers are very helpful.