# Append to matching line only if line doesn't contain keyword

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file let's call it `input.txt`. It has many lines, but the only relevant line contains a model statement;

`height ~ mu gender`

It may also contain;

`height !n ~ mu date_birth !r g`

So the consistent factor to identify the line in regex would be `^height.*~.*$`.
At least that is what I have devised so far.

I would like to append `!r g` to the end line only if `!r g` wasn't already present. I tried to mix answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553556/how-to-append-something-at-the-end-of-a-certain-line-of-the-text), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978504/add-text-at-the-end-of-each-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591744/add-to-the-end-of-a-line-containing-a-pattern-with-sed-or-awk), but I can't figure it out. I would prefer a single command. Have also been playing around with complicated `awk`'s and `sed`'s but I feel this is overly simple that it doesn't need to be too difficult for someone with experience.

**Desired result(s):**

If  `height ~ mu gender` then `height ~ mu gender !r g`.

If `height !bin ~ mu date_birth !r g` then nothing needs to happen.

If `height !bin ~ mu gender` then `height !bin ~ mu gender !r g`

**EDIT:**

So far I tried;

`sed '/^height.*~.*!r.*$/ ! s/$/!r g/' input.txt` correctly skips line if `!g` is present but appends it to each line in `input.txt`.

`sed '/^height.*$/s/$/!r g/' input.txt`, correctly appends only to the matching line, but also if `!r g` was already present.

Comment: you wrote : *If `y !n ~ d e f !r` then nothing need to happen.* which contradicts with your previous requirement *to append `!r g` to the end line only if `!r g` wasn't already present*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thanks forgot the `g`. Edited it accordingly.

Comment: I edited post to make input look more like what my actual script looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/^y.*~.*$/{/!r g/!{s/.*/& !r g/}}' input.txt
```

E.g.

```
$ cat input.txt
y !n ~ d e f !r g
y ~ a b c

$ sed '/^y.*~.*$/{/!r g/!{s/.*/& !r g/}}' input.txt
y !n ~ d e f !r g
y ~ a b c!r g
```

---

**UPDATE**

Above `sed` command will consider all the lines with pattern `^y.*~.*$`, and append `!r g` to the end only if the line does not contain `!r g` in any part of the line.

To change the lines filtered, simply update the starting regex `^y.*~.*$` into what you need.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. It adds the `!r g` to the beginning of the line. I need it at the end. Maybe that wasn't clear. Let me edit my original post.

Comment: @tstev if you need a space before `!r g`, just change the replace string, `&!r g` into `& !r g`

Comment: @tstev Could you simply show a non working input and the expected output. I've used the pattern suggested by you to filter out the required lines. Seems like the primary pattern needs to be improved. I can help if you can show the problem clearly.

Comment: I updated the problem statement. I don't know how to make it more clear.

Comment: @tstev So you just have to change the starting regex with the new one you suggested. Try `sed '/^height.*~.*$/{/!r g/!{s/.*/& !r g/}}' input.txt`. Or do you want to allow any string in place of `height`?

Comment: I know what went wrong, `\r\n` line-endings slipped in the input file. With `dos2unix` it works :) Sorry for that!

Answer (score 2):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/( !r g)?\r?$/," !r g")}1' file
y ~ a b c !r g
y !n ~ d e f !r g
y !n ~ d e f !r g
```

or with the changed data:

```
height ~ mu gender !r g
height !bin ~ mu date_birth !r g
height !bin ~ mu gender !r g
```

Notice the `\r?` in the regex, which is the first part of the Windows line ending `\r\n`. If it exists, it gets replaced.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get `!r g b c `, `!r g~ d e f !r g` and `!r g~ d e f`.

Comment: Humm, probably if you're on Windows or using files with `\r\n` line-ending. Gimme a sec.

Comment: I added `\r?` to the regex. Now it should work but it strips the `\r`s off.

Comment: Ah you identified why the previous answers weren't working for me. Cheers for that!

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with sed.  Firstly, we select lines that begin with `height` and contain a `~`.  With those lines, we can substitute the end of line with `!r g` if the line doesn't already end in that value:

```sed
#/usr/bin/sed -f

/^height .*~/{
/ !r g$/!s/$/ !r g/
# Explanation:
# / !r g/           : select lines marked with the tag
#       !s          : in lines that don't match, substitute
#          $        : end of line
#             !r g  : the tag to add
}
```

### Demonstration

```
$ ./45876917.sed <<END
height ~ mu gender
height !bin ~ mu date_birth !r g
height !bin ~ mu gender
END
height ~ mu gender !r g
height !bin ~ mu date_birth !r g
height !bin ~ mu gender !r g
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with the answer! really helpful

Comment: Glad to help - I'm not a believer in spoon-feeding specific answers without showing how you could get to the same result yourself.  You don't learn very much from code-only answers.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/^y.*~.+/ && !/!r g/{ $0=$0" !r g" }1' input.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It **replaces** at the **beginning** instead of *appending* at the *end* of the line.

Comment: @tstev, it can not be true. `$0=$0" !r g"` will append to the end

Comment: Ok, well `input.txt` contains two lines `height ~ mu gender !r g` and
`height ~ mu gender`. When I run your command adapted for this example; `awk '/^height.*~.+/ && !/!r g/{ $0=$0" !r g" }1' input.txt`. I get `height ~ mu gender !r g` and `!r gt ~ mu gender`. So it correctly skipped the first line as it already contains `!r g` but second line is not correct.

Comment: I have very little knowledge of whats going on with the answer as I am new to unix commands. Perhaps you can try your example on your machine.

Comment: @tstev, look here https://ibb.co/hyBZSQ. It's working on your input lines

Comment: @James Brown identified what the problem was. Apparently some `\r\n` slipped in there :P. Now it works with `dos2unix` https://ibb.co/nhYju5. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

How we append the keyword "world" at the end of the line in case it is missing from there:

```bash
echo "hello world
hello
hello world" | awk '{ print $0, ($NF=="world")? "" : "world"; }'

# # Output:
# Hello world
# Hello world
# Hello world
```

A practical example: Append the keyword "[not installed]" at the end of the line in case the opposite keyword ("[installed*") is missing from there:

```bash
# By default 'apt list' will only print '[installed]' or '[installed,automatic]' at the end of the installed packages 
# and nothing at the end of non-installed packages. Creating more verbosity by piping to awk
apt -qq list pv gawk gnome-disk-utility | awk '{ print $0, ( match( $NF , "\\[installed" ) ) ? "" : "[not installed]"; }'

# Output:
# gawk/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 1:5.1.0-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic] 
# gawk/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1:5.1.0-1ubuntu0.1 i386 [not installed]
# gnome-disk-utility/jammy,now 42.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed] 
# pv/jammy 1.6.6-1build2 amd64 [not installed]
```